# Integration - $p\int_\frac{S}{a}^T(0-at)dt$

Tags: integration

I have a formula:
$$p\int_\frac{S}{a}^T(0-at)dt$$

I did the following:

$$p(\int_\frac{S}{a}^T0dt-\int_\frac{S}{a}^Tatdt)$$
$$=p(0-\frac{aT^2}{2}-\frac{\frac{S^2}{a}}{2})$$
$$=p(0-\frac{a^2T^2}{2a}-\frac{S^2}{2a})$$

Assume $aT=Q$

$$=\frac{-P(Q-S)^2}{2a}$$

Am I right?

But the answer I want is 
$$=\frac{P(Q-S)^2}{2a}$$

Am I doing anything wrong for the integration or may be my formula $p\int_\frac{S}{a}^T(0-at)dt$ is not correct in the first place?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P\int_\frac{S}{a}^T(0-at)\:\text{dt}$$

$$= -P\int_\frac{S}{a}^Tat\:\text{dt}$$

$$= -Pa \cdot \frac{t^2}{2} |_{t =S/a}^{t =T}$$

$$= -\frac{Pa}{2} \cdot (T^2 - \frac{S^2}{a^2})$$

$aT = Q \Rightarrow T = Q/a$

$$= -\frac{Pa}{2} \cdot (\frac{Q^2}{a^2} - \frac{S^2}{a^2})$$

$$= \frac{P(S^2 - Q^2)}{2a}$$